# Spring Securirty Granted Authorities always return empty

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to gather user permissions from Active Directory in my Spring 4.0.6 application, using Spring Security 3.2.4.

Some details:

- Authentication works. I can get the current username.
- Pre-authentication is done by JBoss 7.2 using JCIFS (NTLM).
- LDAP server works, so host and port are correct.
- Domain is correct.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@PropertySource( "classpath:/resources/ldap-config.properties" )
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value( "${domain}" )
    private String strDomain;

    @Value( "${ldap.host}" )
    private String strHost;

    @Value( "${ldap.basedn}" )
    private String strBaseDn;

    @Value( "${ldap.userdn}" )
    private String strUserDn;

    @Value( "${ldap.userdn.password}" )
    private String strUserDnPassword;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean 
    public ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper grantedAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return new ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(strDomain, strHost);
        activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);

        activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setAuthoritiesMapper(this.grantedAuthoritiesMapper());

        return activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {

        authenticationManagerBuilder
        .authenticationProvider(this.activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .jee();
    }
}
```

**ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper.java**

```
public class ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper implements GrantedAuthoritiesMapper {

    // Constants for group defined in LDAP
    private final String ROLE_ADMIN = "A_SPECIFIC_ADMIN_GROUP_IN_AD";
    private final String ROLE_USER = "A_SPECIFIC_GROUP_IN_AD";

    public ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper() {
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        Set<SecurityContextAuthority> roles = EnumSet.noneOf(SecurityContextAuthority.class);

        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {

            System.out.println("GrantedAuthority : " + authority.getAuthority());

            if (ROLE_ADMIN.equals(authority.getAuthority())) {
                roles.add(SecurityContextAuthority.ROLE_ADMIN);
            }

            if (ROLE_USER.equals(authority.getAuthority())) {
                roles.add(SecurityContextAuthority.ROLE_USER);
            }
        }

        return roles;
    }

}
```

**SecurityContextAuthority.java**

```
public enum SecurityContextAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

    ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

---

What I got in my console:

```
2014-10-14 14:04:02,557 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) MY_DOMAIN\MY_USERNAME
2014-10-14 14:04:02,557 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Authorities: []
2014-10-14 14:04:02,557 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Auth Type: NTLM
2014-10-14 14:04:02,557 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Is Authenticated: true
```

With debugging turned on, I got the follow extra details:

```
2014-10-16 11:10:50,959 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Checking secure context token: null
2014-10-16 11:10:50,959 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) PreAuthenticated J2EE principal: MY_DOMAIN\MY_USERNAME
2014-10-16 11:10:50,959 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) preAuthenticatedPrincipal = MY_DOMAIN\MY_USERNAME, trying to authenticate
2014-10-16 11:10:50,959 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) J2EE roles [[]] mapped to Granted Authorities: [[]]
2014-10-16 11:10:50,960 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider
2014-10-16 11:10:50,960 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) PreAuthenticated authentication request: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@f99efc97: Principal: MY_DOMAIN\MY_USERNAME; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesWebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FaMwocWCdZawHD1GvwUcNg8S; []; Not granted any authorities
2014-10-16 11:10:50,960 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Authentication success: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@661034c: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@f99c56bc: Username: MY_DOMAIN\MY_USERNAME; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesWebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: FaMwocWCdZawHD1GvwUcNg8S; []; Not granted any authorities
```

**Other debugging info:**

- Authorities are always empty
- mapAuthorities and getAuthority never seem to be invoked. Adding breakpoints does nothing at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved your problem. However, your description helped me to solve mine. I implemented the authorities mapper almost based on your code and it is working just fine. The only thing I can see that could lead to an empty authorities field is the field is empty when calling the mapper or none of the authorities in the argument map to your AD roles defined as ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN.